# Editing woocommerce single product layout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I wanted to edit the layout of the product detail page in the woocommerce plugin. As per several tutorials, I put `content-single-product.php` file in a `woocommerce` folder in my theme and I edited the content and it had been working fine, until I found out one of these days it wasn't working. It could be caused by other people working on it also. The file is still there but altering the content doesn't seem to affect anything on the frontend. Additionally, the content displayed seems like a normal post content - with title, content and area for the comments. Then I tried altering `index.php`, `single.php`, `page.php` if the content is displayed by those templates - but it doesn't seem so. I also directly altered the plugin's `single-product.php` file but it doesn't seem to have any effect at all. At this time, I have ran out of all options of debugging - can anyone point me out how I can debug this problem more or point me out how else this could have been caused? Thanks.

**Edit**
After some inspection, I found out that it is another template file that is used. I have another template with path `template-parts/content.php` and for some reason that I don't know it is this file that is used.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the website is still using the theme you think it is.

You mention other people working on the site - make sure one of them hasn't changed the theme.

Answer (score 0):

> the content displayed seems like a normal post content - with title, content and area for the comments.

This gives me the idea that the product is not being identified as such and treated as a generic post. I'd check the post types and see if anything went wrong with the product post type.